# Only COUNT/COUNTIF a cell if the cell next to it contains data

Tags: microsoft-excel

In a typical day, we have anywhere from 10-60 meetings split into 30 minute blocks, (3 people could attend @ 10:30, 6 @ 11:00, 15 @ 12:00 etc.) but it's rarely the same.

I am wondering, is it possible to put together (or if there is already) a formula that would only count a cell if there was a name next to it?

For example:

```
11:00 Chris  
11:00   
11:00 John
```

So for my summary, it would say next to the 11:00 that there would be 2 people (1 isn't counted because a name hasn't been allocated in the nearby cell)

Obviously i'd replicate the formula for the other times.

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Comment: Look into [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)

Comment: Just looking for a formula, as mentioned I'm not an excel wiz. Just looking for help, suggestions. I'm not sure what formula would assist in captured allocated times..

Comment: Try the SUMPRODUCT function. https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function

Answer (score 0):

You could use a COUNTIFS formula, which uses multiple criteria.

**Criteria 1**: Time matches time.

**Criteria 2**: Name is not blank.

Cell F2 formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$6,E2,$B$2:$B$6,"<>"&"")
```

Drag it down and you're done. Results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Isolated!

Comment: @Sean If this resolves your question, then please consider clicking on the Accepting flag for this answer.